# Animating navigation only to and from specific pages in Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, customization

Is there a way to set an animation between two specific pages? I'm using onGenerateRoute to change animations between pages, but it can only filter through the page it's being navigated to.

Example: I have PageA, PageB and PageC, i can change the navigation animation when i'm navigating to PageC, but it doesn't matter if i'm navigating from PageA or PageB, the animation will always be the same.

What i'm asking for is if there is a way to make a custom animation specifically when i'm navigating between PageA and PageC and PageB and PageC.

Comment: Verify the code in the above section.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Create Animated Navigation like this:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: Page1(),
    ),
  );
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(_createRoute());
          },
          child: const Text('Go!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Route _createRoute() {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => const Page2(),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      const begin = Offset(0.0, 1.0);
      const end = Offset.zero;
      const curve = Curves.ease;

      var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

      return SlideTransition(
        position: animation.drive(tween),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page2({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Page 2'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```